# How to configure nginx to make ssh server via subdomain.domain.tld:80 available

Tags: ssh, nginx, subdomain

I want to make the ssh server on port 22 available through a subdomain on port 80.

I thought it should by something like this:

```
server {
    listen          ssh.domain.tld:80;
    server_name     ssh.domain.tld;

    location / {
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:22;
    }
}
```

But it won't work. nginx will accept this and start with this configuration, but I only get empty responses from `ssh.domain.tld:80`.

What am I missing?

Comment: I found what I need here: https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_tcp_proxy_module/blob/master/README
This enable me to forward tcp traffic. Exactly the thing I need, I will give a detailed answer as soon as I figured the details out^^

Comment: ... and 3 years later?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Nginx Version 1.9.0,NGINX support ngx_stream_core_module module, it should be enabled with the --with-stream. When stream module is enable they are possible to ssh protocol tcp proxy

```
stream {
upstream ssh {
    server localhost:22;
}
    server {
    listen        80;
    proxy_pass    ssh;
} }
```

https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/tcp-load-balancing/

Answer (score 2):

You should use [sslh](http://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh.shtml).

Configure nginx to run on a different port than 80, say 800, and then configure sslh to redirect web traffic to that port in `/etc/default/sslh.conf` file.

This setup may take 15 min. or less.

Answer (score -2):

basically you're looking in the wrong place:

- stock nginx can proxy web and/or email traffic, it doesn't handle ssh traffic at all
- the subdomain is a dns isue: configure it in your dns settings, you need an `A` and/or `AAAA` record linking `ssh.domain.tld` to your ssh server's `ip-adres`
- the port your ssh server listens on is a ssh server setting (see `man sshd_config` specifically the `ListenAddress` and `Port` directives)

Comment: I think this is no longer the case, perhaps the answer should be updated?